# How to get a box like this on a webpage?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

am looking for a way to get a box like this on a webpage [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f63ZM.png)

This is actually reddit's theme and I would like to understand how to create a box like this with a different color and then another box sticked with it in white. I couldn't come up with a term to google for this, nonetheless, I still googled things like ''box with css'', ''box table in css'' etc. but no luck.

What this is called and how to exactly do this?

Comment: css border-radius

Comment: one parent div with border radius like 10px and overflow hidden, and then one child div with the background and then whatever you need

Answer (score 0):

The height/width are probably going to be off for what your ultimate code will need, but with this snippet you can get the idea of adding border-radius to an outer `card` element, and then border-top-right-radius and border-top-left-radius to the inner `card-header` element to get the desired effect.

The `display: flex` on the `card-header` element allows you to use `justify-content: space-between` to push the title and the ellipsis away from each other with minimal code.

I added some other styling to just give the same sense of colors, font style, etc.

```css
.body {
  display: block;
  background: #FAFAFA;
  width: 1000px:
  height: 1000px;
  padding: 25px;
}

.card {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
}

.card .card-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  background: #4BA2AF;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <span class="title">COMMUNITY DETAILS</span>
      <span class="ellipsis">…</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```